# How to concatenate LPTSTR with a char array?

Tags: c

```
BOOL test(LPTSTR a) {
char res[1024];
strcat(res,"before");
strcat(res,a); //<--
strcat(res,"after");
printf("%s",res);
}
```

How to concatenate LPTSTR with a char array?

Edit:
I have another functions which is returning a string in LPTSTR format. i cannot change this functions.

The problem is that the statement strcpy(res,a) does not compile. Says thats "LPTSTR" and "const char *" is not compatible.

Beside of this you are all right there are more problems with this snippet, but its not real just for showing the context of the strcpy statement.

Main problem is how to convert a lptstr to const char *, to can concatenate.

Comment: (a) Initialize `res`. To use `strcat(res, "before")`, `res` should be initialized to contain a string, possibly an empty string. (b) Aside from (a), what is not working for you?

Comment: OT: learn how to format code properly. As examples you can look at the samples in your C text book.

Comment: You are declaring a function that returns BOOL but not returning a value.

Comment: Please [edit] and show how you call `test` as well as the declaration of the relevant variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code:

```
BOOL test(LPTSTR a) {
  char res[1024];
  strcat(res,"before");    // you're contatenating a string to res which is not
                           // initialized and which therefore contains garbage
  strcat(res,a);
  strcat(res,"after");
  printf("%s",res);
}                          // test is declared to return a BOOL but you 
                           // don't return anything, the compiler should warn you
```

You probably want this:

```
void test(LPTSTR a) {
  char res[1024];
  strcpy(res,"before");
  strcat(res,a);
  strcat(res,"after");
  printf("%s",res);
}
```

Is there a reason why you use `LPTSTR`? Do you know what it is? The subject is quite vast. Probably you want to forget about `LPTSTR` and just use `char*`:

```
void test(char *a)
...
```

But without more information it's hard to tell.

Comment: Moreover, as "res" has limited size and the size of the "a" parameter is not known, it could be more secured to use strncat() to prevent overflows...